# Customizing which tests to run with JUnit @Parameters?

Tags: java, junit

I have the following code, where each `url` in `listOne` is tested with the method `testItem`:

```
@Parameters(name="{0}")
public static Collection<Object[]> data() throws Exception {
    final Set<String> listOne = getListOne();
    final Collection<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final String url : listOne) {
        data.add(new Object[] { url });
    }
    return data;
}

@Test
public void testItem() {
    driverOne.makeDecision(urlToTest);
    assertTrue(driverOne.success(urlToTest);
}
```

What if I now wanted to add a second list, `listTwo`, and run a test method defined as follows on JUST the items of `listTwo` (but not `listOne`?)

```
@Test
public void testItemAlternate() {
    driverTwo.makeDecision(urlToTest);
    assertTrue(driverTwo.success(urlToTest));
}
```

That is, I want `driverOne` to make the decision for all URLs in `listOne`, and I want `driverTwo` to make the decision for all URLs in `listTwo`. What is the best way to translate this to code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cited from: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests

> The custom runner Parameterized implements parameterized tests. When running a parameterized test class, instances are created for the cross-product of the test methods and the test data elements.

Thus, I assume No, that's not possible.

If you want to do such a thing I guess that you either

(1) will need to construct two test classes one for each test to be executed with the first collection and one for each test to be executed with the second collection or

(2) will need to use another mechanism besides the `@Parameters` annotation, maybe hand-crafted.

Answer (score 0):

You could include some test set identifier in your test set data itself, and then use the org.junit.Assume class to help:

```
@Test
public void testItem() {
    org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(testSetId.equals("TEST_SET_1"));
    driverOne.makeDecision(urlToTest);
    assertTrue(driverOne.success(urlToTest);
}

@Test
public void testItemAlternate() {
    org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(testSetId.equals("TEST_SET_2"));
    driverTwo.makeDecision(urlToTest);
    assertTrue(driverTwo.success(urlToTest));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a completely different answer, there exists [junit-dataprovider](http://java.dzone.com/articles/alternative-junit)